# Getting activity reference in AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have an `AndroidViewModel` that I'm using `GoogleSignIn` with. The `GoogleSignIn` method I'm using requires an activity context to perform `SilentSignIn`. I have tried using the `Application` context that is provided with `AndroidViewModel` using `getApplication()`.

Although it doesn't throw an error in Android Studio

[image]

at run time it throws the error:

`Cannot cast application context`

How can I get reference to the Activity that uses the ViewModel?

```
public class MembersViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public MembersViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repo = new MembersRepo(application, this);
    }


public void signIn(){
   Log.d(TAG, "onGetMembers: Invalid Access Token...Logging in again");
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                     .requestIdToken(getApplication().getString(R.string.idclient))
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();
   GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplication(), gso);
```

I have an `activity` that uses a `MembersFragment` that uses the `MembersViewModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get reference to the Activity that uses the ViewModel?

You can't.

Instead, have your `MembersViewModel` emit an event that your activity observes and responds to by doing whatever it is that you need to have done with the activity. "Emit an event" could be via an RxJava `PublishSubject` or a carefully-constructed "single live event" form of `LiveData`. If you were using Kotlin, a `BroadcastChannel` would be another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you parse a `Context` parameter into the signIn method so that when you call it you will get the right activity context.

live `public void signIn(Context context) { }`   so that you can get the right activity context